# New project option for PlantUML plugin does not display using Netbeans 8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-8, plantuml

I have Netbeans 8 running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have installed the PlantUML plugin from the Netbeans plugin repository and restarted Netbeans.

The PlantUML options tab shows in the options dialog, so the plugin is is installed; however, there is no new UML project in the new projects dialog.

I have tried various things such as uninstalling / reinstalling plugin and Netbeans as well starting with a completely new Netbeans 8 installation after deleting the settings directory.

How could I get the new UML project option to display properly?

Comment: The plugin author has confirmed this problem exists on Ubuntu but it does not occur in Windows.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/plantumlnb/tickets/21/

Comment: @ShaggyInjun that's my ticket. :) I was hoping we could help find the solution.

Comment: Will try to find some time for this over the weekend !!

Comment: Oh you're the project owner? I didn't realize. :-) Thanks. Not trying to rush you, of course. Just thought maybe some extra hands would be helpful. :-)

Comment: There is no need to create a new project to use the PlantUML plugin. Just create new PlantUML Diagram and [use the Files tab to manage and preview it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4jkn7c37duitj9/plantuml-plugin.png?dl=0). OpenSUSE 12.3

Comment: @Gilbertoca, you're right. You right-click an existing project and create a new PlantUML file or from existing sources. Please post as an answer and I'll credit you.

Comment: Apologies to @ShaggyInjun - I don't remember if I tried this before but probably didn't. I also just updated the plugin to 1.5 so I don't really know if that had an effect or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create a new project to use the [PlantUML plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49069/plantuml). Just create new PlantUML Diagram and [use the Files tab to manage and preview it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4jkn7c37duitj9/plantuml-plugin.png?dl=0).